# Repository pattern's answer to complex / non-model specific queries (i.e. reporting / aggregate data)

Tags: .net, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I've been reading up on the Repository Pattern and struggling to find a solid answer on how people approach situations where the data returned isn't just your standard models (i.e. NOT `Customer 1..* Account`)

I'm building an analytically system which returns data that is aggregated, sometimes spanning many tables. Additionally, these tables might have millions of records within them being joined. In short, my typical result sets are not my core domain models, but (sometimes extreme) spans, permutations and aggregations of them.

In the past, I have simply constructed my query and return the results as a custom result set (granted this gave access to the ORM from my upper layers of my system and thus did not separate my system from the knowledge of the ORM being used).

**Is the repository pattern not a good fit here? How have others approached this type of scenario? It feels a bit like square-peg/round-hole.**

*For reference, I'm developing in C# .Net using ASP MVC with a MSSQL DB.*

### UPDATE

While my scenario is largely reporting based, I'm still dealing with the individual entities that make up the data the reports are based on.

**As (*JUST*) an example** : I still need my `Customer` entity and that customer still needs to have `Orders` that they generate through the system. My domain POCOS work well here in this scenario. The issue comes up after receiving MANY `Orders` and having to report on them along with their many joined, aggregated tables in a format that doesn't match anywhere close to my existing domain objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the repository pattern applies in your scenario, for analytic data in particular. A repository brings the biggest benefit when you not only need to query but also to persist. Moreover, with certain exceptions, repositories should be one to one with aggregates, not just any entity or value object.

In your scenario, there is not reason you can't just query the data with SQL and return simple read-only objects. You can still reap some of the benefits of a repository by encapsulating these queries so that consumers aren't required to call SQL directly. Expose them as simple service calls. This can apply to [all queries in general](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, FYI - I've updated my question to expand on the fact that the system is not just strictly a reporting platform, also involves "writes" as they relate to the data to be reported on.

Comment: The [read-model pattern](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) that I linked to still applies. You'd have a repository for customers and orders, assuming they were both aggregates. Also take a look at [Effective Aggregate Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=139).